# commiting to branch which is itself a checkout branch

Tags: bazaar

I have repo located at `A`, of which I did a checkout to `B`, which I checked out to `C` (so `C` is bound to `B` and `B` to `A`).

I did some changes in `C`, did `bzr commit` on `B`, but I do not seem to see changes in `B` automatically.

Is this an expected behavior or did I screw something up without knowing?

Answer (score 1):

Checkouts of checkouts are not supported, and Bazaar will generally refuse to do bind to a branch that is already bound to something else.

How did you create C, is it actually bound to B ? "bzr info C" should tell you.

Comment: Additionally, committing to a bound branch will not update the upstream branch's working tree. You have to use `bzr update` in the upstream branch's working tree to get it up to date with the tip of the branch.

Comment: Ok, I see that branches in `C` are actually not bound (though I created them with `checkout B`), and running `bzr bind B` is no-op, though without giving any error. How can I push changes from `C` to `B` then? They are shown as pending merges (which are ignored by `push B`).

Comment: Ohh... now the branch has a push branch; after local commit, `push` aborts with **This transport does not update the working tree of: B**? Eh I think I will just copy files and merge manually...

Comment: It doesn't abort, it just warns you that it won't update the working tree. It will update the branch.